# uwsgi permission denied on chdir that does have permissions for that uid

Tags: permissions, uwsgi

I am using uWSGI (behind nginx) *without* Emperor, run as a `systemd` service.

uwsgi.service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/CONSTANd++/uwsgi_config.ini
(...)
```

uwsgi_config.ini:

```
(...)
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
chdir = /var/www/CONSTANd++/constandpp_web/constandpp_web
(...)
```

terminal:

```
$ ls -la /var/www/CONSTANd++/constandpp_web/constandpp_web
drwxrwxr-x 5 pdiracdelta www-data  4096 Sep  6 10:42 .
(...)
```

Clearly, this folder has all permissions for the www-data group, but still when I start this uWSGI service the uWSGI log complains:

```
(...)
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
chdir() to /var/www/CONSTANd++/constandpp_web/constandpp_web
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 2591]
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1613]
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? If I remove the `uid=www-data` from the uwsgi_config.ini everything starts fine, but then of course the files created by my WSGI application have root ownership, which I don't want.

Comment: What about higher level directories? Did you check their permissions? You can not `cd` unless you have enough privileges to access all directories!

Comment: Are you sure? I just did `cd /` as my own regular user and that brings me to `/` just fine. Or does it work differently with uWSGI's `chdir()` command?
Of course, `/var/` is not owned by the www-data group, as you probably suspected...

Comment: "Having enough privilege" does not mean to own the directory!

Comment: @Khaled this issue came up again. So how do I give www-data privileges to `cd` to a directory it does not own? (to a subdirectory of /var/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the www-data user needs permissions for the 'complete' path to your file/folder. This maybe be trickier than you think:

1. The www-data user needs to have `+x` permissions to be able to `cd` to a folder ...
2. ... and also in each *parent* folder specified in the path you are using ...
3. ... and *also*, if a *symlink* is involved, in each parent folder of the *absolute* path to that file/folder.

You can check all (both relative and absolute) path permissions in one command using `namei -m <any_path>`.

This is answer is partially based on @Khaled's comments and some more searching: